# How to write json data into a column based on the value in another column in CSV file python

Tags: python, json, database, pandas, csv

I have a large CSV file with the values: ​​Date, Store, Empl_ID, Skill. 
And i want to create a new column is a JSON : Empl with skill working in a store for a day

My CSV file:

```
Date        Store   ID_Empl Skill
20190517    9999    111756  1
20190517    9999    146465  2
20190519    C211    169838  3
20190519    C211    176859  1
20190521    C211    146465  2
20190510    D211    130171  1
20190510    D211    111756  2
```

CSV file I want:

```
Date        Store       Empl_Skill
20190517    9999    {111765: 1, 146465: 2}
20190519    C211    {169838: 3, 176859: 1}
20190521    C211    {146465: 2}
20190510    D211    { 130171: 1, 111756: 2}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/32328/export-pandas-to-dictionary-by-combining-multiple-row-values) will help

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1º Read csv file using [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):**

```
#import pandas as pd #import  pandas library
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)



#Date        Store   ID_Empl Skill
#20190517    9999    111756  1
#20190517    9999    146465  2
#20190519    C211    169838  3
#20190519    C211    176859  1
#20190521    C211    146465  2
#20190510    D211    130171  1
#20190510    D211    111756  2
```

**2º Obtain output DataFrame using [groupby.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):**

```
new_df=df.groupby(['Date','Store']).apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x['ID_Empl'],x['Skill']))).rename('Empl_Skill').reset_index()
print(new_df)

       Date Store              Empl_Skill
0  20190510  D211  {130171: 1, 111756: 2}
1  20190517  9999  {111756: 1, 146465: 2}
2  20190519  C211  {169838: 3, 176859: 1}
3  20190521  C211             {146465: 2}
```

3 **Save csv using [pd.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):**

```
new_df.to_csv('new_data.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks very much

Comment: Sorry, but i have a problem. Data in the "Empl Skill" column after using zip have deleted the duplicate values. For example: if i have 2 values 130171:1 in one Date and Store, it only show one. Pls help me